# Redirecting user to a VF page after executing site.login

Tags: force.com-sites, customer-portal

We are using force.com sites to build a application portal. Customer portal is being used in conjunction to enable self registration.

When a user tries to login ... we are executing the force.com site method like below

```
PageReference p = Site.login(username, password, '/apex/VF_ApplicantHomePage?Id=005J0000001HVIK');
return p;
```

However, I get an error when I try to login which says 
Error: Error occurred while loading a Visualforce page

The URL formed after login action is

```
https://.cs10.force.com/ApplicationSubmission/VF_ApplicantHomePage?Id=005J0000001HVIK
```

Has anyone done the same thing? Can you suggest the work around?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Can you check once site has access to the  VF_ApplicantHomePage , if not add this vf page to sites through

Develop -> Sites-> Force.com Site -> Set Visualforce Page

Even if error also comes, need to check on the permissions on the objects used in the vf page   for the profiles used for site login.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The object which the landing page was referring to was not available to the portal. I updated the object properties and was able to redirect succesful login to the landing page